# ¿Por qué me aparece este error? No puedo escribir un String con un TEdit en Delphi

Tags: string, pascal, type

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonPlusLessClick(Sender: TObject);
var
pMinus: Real;

begin
  pMinus := StrToFloat(txtResult.Text);
  txtResult := FloatToStr(-1 * pMinus);
end;
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente: E2010 Incompatible types: 'TEdit' and 'string'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txtResult` es un `TEdit`.
`FloatToStr` devuelve un `String`.

La parte derecha/izquierda de esta asignación no son iguales:

```
txtResult := FloatToStr(-1 * pMinus);
```

Supongo que quieres/debes hacer esto:

```
txtResult.Text := FloatToStr(-1 * pMinus);
```

Comment: Perfecto, solucionado, gracias.